# Poisson with different stages

Tags: probability

Assume that “dangerous voltage spikes” are hitting certain electronic equipment according to a Poisson process with the rate λ.  The equipment needs a time period of length μ (constant) to completely recover from the spike. However, if the next spike arrives during the recovery period the equipment is irreparably damaged and has to be replaced. Otherwise the equipment survives intact and ready for the next spike.

(a)     Find the expected “lifetime” of the equipment.

(b)    Find the expected number of “dangerous voltage spikes” the equipment will get during its lifetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interarrival times $U_1,\ldots,$ of a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$ are i.i.d. Exp($\lambda$). Thus, for each of the inter-arrival times, you can associate a Bernoulli random variable $B_i$ with success probability $P(U_i \leq \mu)$, which is $1$ if the equipment dies due to the $i$-th arrival. Then, you just need to calculate the first time $B_i$ process (which is i.i.d. Bernoulli) is $1$, which follows a geometric distribution with the same parameter as $B_i$ to find the expected number of dangerous voltage spikes until the machine dies.

The time between voltage spikes is i.i.d. Exp($\lambda)$, so expected lifetime is the mean of an Exp($\lambda$) distribution * average number of spikes til the machine dies (which was calculated prior). [ You can phrase this as a consequence of the PASTA-type property (Poisson arrivals see time averages) - I leave the formulation as an exercise to you. ]

Edit: The first spike cannot kill the system, so have to exclude the first $U_1$. But $B_2,\ldots$ do still form a Bernoulli process and the number of spikes after the first one which are needed to kill the system are still Geometric with the same probability. So, the number of spikes needed to kill the system is 1+ geometric distribution with same parameter as $B_i$. This is a manifestation of the memoryless property of exponential / geometric distributions.